# How many ways to color grid

Tags: combinations

In the 2x2 square grid below, how many ways can I color each region one of 4 colors so that orthogonally adjacent regions are different colors? Assume the grid is fixed in place and cannot be rotated, etc.

(I couldn’t get the picture but it’s just a chessboard, but 2 by 2 instead)

I don’t understand what orthogonally adjacent means. I searched it up but there isn’t like a diagram or a clear explanation of what it is. Also, I know that this problem can be split into cases, but I don’t know how. Can somebody please help me do this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Orthogonally adjacent is next to each other vertically or horizontally, but not diagonally.

Comment: _Can somebody please help me do this problem?_ That seems too broad/vague, outside the scope of Stack Overflow. You might have better luck on https://cs.stackexchange.com.